# How to import the imagesLoaded and Masonry libs that come with WP in a Gutenberg block?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, masonry, react

I'm trying to develop a Gutenberg block that needs the Masonry lib to work:

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);
const {
    attributes: { images, column_width, gap },
    setAttributes,
} = props;

useEffect(() => {

    imagesLoaded(containerRef.current, function () {
        var msnry = new Masonry(containerRef.current, {
            itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
            columnWidth: column_width,
            gutter: gap,
        });
    });

}, [images, column_width, gap]);
```

But I don't know how to import/use the imagesLoaded and Masonry libs (non-jQuery version) that come with WP in this situation.

Can I do something like:

```
import { imagesLoaded } from '@wordpress/....';
import { Masonry } from '@wordpress/....';
```

Thanks

Comment: where is gutenberg using it? Are you sure it does? I can find no references to a Masonry library in JS files in the gutenberg github repo, likewise a search for `imagesLoaded` gives zero results

Comment: No, they are not used anywhere in the Gutenberg code. So, it's not possible to use any JS libs bundled in WP core in Gutenberg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing a block with [`@wordpress/scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/), `wp-scripts` uses [@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin/) to allow you to `import` dependencies from WordPress by replacing the `import` statements with references to the global variables loaded by the enqueued scripts.

For example, this:

```
import { useEffect } from '@wordpress/element'
```

Will become:

```
const { useEffect } = wp.element;
```

And `wp-element` will be added as a dependency to the enqueued script to ensure that `wp.element` is available.

This process works when importing the modules listed in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin/#webpack) for the dependency extraction plugin:

- `@wordpress/*`
- `jquery`
- `lodash-es`
- `lodash`
- `moment`
- `react-dom`
- `react`

For any other bundled libraries you would need to enqueue them as a dependency manually and reference the global variable as you would if you were using the library anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there a way to specify the `imagesLoaded` and `Masonry` libs deps for the editorScript prop in the block.json file? Or do I need to use the `enqueue_block_assets` hook?

Comment: @leemon at that point there's no difference between what you're doing and how it would work if I created `myjquerycode.js` and used `wp_enqueue_script` on it, the needed variables would be in exactly the same place for both situations, the `import` syntax would be completely irrelevant. There's no way to specify the additional dependencies via `block.json` though

Comment: @leemon In the `script`, `viewScript` etc. properties in block.json you can pass an array of values, and if you include the registered handle of a script it will also enqueue that script. There's an example in the docs here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#wpdefinedasset So you absolutely can declare script dependencies in block.json.